# Reverse an integer array using same array variable

Tags: javascript

I want to use the same variable `array` to output the reverse an integer array. But, I only got the first value print out. Not sure where I did wrong.
Here is my code:

```js
let array = [3, 8, 9, 6, 4, 2]
reverseArray(array);
function reverseArray(array){
    let left =0;
    for(i =  0; i <= array.length - 1; i++){
        let right = array.length - 1 - i;
        let temp = right;
        right = left;
        left = temp;
        array = array[left];
    }
    console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Comment: `array = array[left];`??

Comment: May it be a typo? `array = array[left];` should be `array[right] = array[left];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you changing index so `right` use to store index not value and in the last line `array = array[left]` is you  are trying to give value and that is `array[0] = 1`  so that's why 1 is coming
Right way to do this

```
let array = [3, 8, 9, 6, 4,2]
reverseArray(array);

function reverseArray(array){
for(i =  0; i <= (array.length - 1)/2; i++){// need to iterate only half otherwise it remain same so for exampale 0th index replace with 4th index and 4th with 0 so at last both at their same position
    let right = array.length - 1 - i;
    let temp = array[right];
    array[right] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;

}
console.log(array);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a learning exercise, note that you are iterating too many times:

```js
function reverseArray(array){
    const len = array.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < len/2; ++i) {
        const temp = array[i];
        const tail = len - i - 1;
        array[i] = array[tail];
        array[tail] = temp;
    }
}

const array = [3, 8, 9, 6, 4, 2];
reverseArray(array);
console.log(array);
```

As others have pointed out, the reason for truncation is the fact that you assigned an array element to the `array` variable, turning it from an array into a scalar.

"In real life", you should use [`array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Answer (score 1):

it's because you set the array as a single value by doing `array = array[left]`.

you just override the array variable and placing a single element inside it.

changing this line to `array[right] = array[left]` would be a good start.

if you want to fix it all, you need to iterate only through HALF of the array (so that you won't reverse it twice - back to normal), and make the whole swap (not just replace one element):

```js
let array = [3, 8, 9, 6, 4, 2]
reverseArray(array);
function reverseArray(array){
    for(i =  0; i < array.length / 2; i++){
        let right = array.length - 1 - i;
        let temp = array[right];
        array[right] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
    console.log(array);
}
```

Note: if you want to reverse an array you can simply use the [array prototype "reverse"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function like this:

```js
let array = [3, 8, 9, 6, 4, 2];
array = array.reverse();

console.log(array);
```

Comment: `array[right] = array[left]` this is not valid result!!! just run and check your result

Comment: i know that, just said that it would be a nice place to start, the problem now is that he only swaps one element (he should also save the `right` element and place in the `left` index

Answer (score 0):

Just use build in NodeJs function:

```
array.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing wrong is

```
array = array[left]
```

On the right side of this equation is a value of array at a specific index while on the right side of this array is a whole array